# 3D-Blocks in Visual Studio UWP

Tags: vb.net, xaml, 3d, uwp

We have a request to create 3D blocks both in cube format and curved formats and place them on a C# VB app.  We need the ability to change the colors of the blocks based on some back end code.

It appears from my research that there may be a way to "fake" it with some perspective views in VB or I need to turn to a 3rd party program.

Does anyone know how a person would go about creating 3d blocks inside VB?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, we would need more information. Can they move in all axis? Can they rotate? Do you need z-buffer? What type of perspective you need? Can they just be images? ect...

Comment: WPF supports 3D shapes and can be used from both C# and VB.  But this question is a bit too broad as asked.